# Need help with mirror! only moves the top and bottom vertices, not the middle v them!

Tags: modeling, mirror

Need help with mirror, it only moves the top and bottom vertices, not the middle v them!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to move the middle vertices you need to select them. You can select multiple vertices by pressing shift (select the first vert then hold down shift and select the second), press c for circle selection (click and hold to select) or b for box selection (click and drag to select).